# Project Explorer and workspace issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i'm running Eclipse luna and my eclipse suddenly showing like this. This happens whenever i see xml in Graphical layout. I don't know what made it to be. Any help would be much better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Windows -> Perspective -> Other -> Select Java (default) and open Windows again and select reset perspective
Or 
2. Windows -> ResetPersspective

hope you help

Comment: Done but the problem is still remains.